# How can I separate faces without the edges?

Tags: modeling

So I am doing this tutorial from Cinema 4D, and I am trying to do it in Blender.

My question is: How am I supposed to separate the faces of an Icosphere from each other as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.cinema4dtutorial.net/?p=1293)? (part 1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the same functionality with **Extrude individual Faces** (the easiest way to access this function is by pressing <kbd>space</kbd> and just typing it in).

If your Pivot Point is set to **Individual Origins** and you are in **Face select mode**, you can then also scale the individual faces down independantly with <kbd>S</kbd>.

With **Select** > **Inverse** and <kbd>X</kbd> > **Faces**, you can delete everything in-between.

Steps:[image: Step-by-step result]

Comment: As an addendum, you can use *P* > *By Loose Parts* to make each individual section a separate object.

Comment: Also *Extrude individual faces* is accessible with Alt+E (IMO easier than the space key)

Comment: Thanks, that helped but maybe I was to vague, I also wanted to know how to do the effect with the empty making the faces rotate as well. If no one knows how that is ok.

Comment: In my opinion, you should create a second question for that. That's relatively unrelated and a lot more complex to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the most direct method.

- Select All
- Mesh -> Edge -> Edge Split
- Set the pivot point **Individual Origins** in the 3D view header.
- Scale the faces.

Answer (score 4):

You can duplicate this functionality using the [*inset tool*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Duplicating/Inset) (<kbd>`I`</kbd> in *Edit mode*)

1. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> twice to inset and enable *individual*:
   [image]
   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and select *Faces*:
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a (kind of) hidden tool in *Edit Mode* called [*Edge Split*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Edges#Edge_Split) (different from the modifier). You can search for it with <kbd>Space</kbd> or access it via the *Edge Specials Menu* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>). It will split each selected face along it's edge.

You can then use <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts* to make each face a separate object.

Comment: *Edge split* is accessible with Ctrl+E

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks. Update the answer :D

Answer (score 4):

1. Add an [EdgeSplit modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Edge_Split) and set *Edge Angle* to 0.
2. Add a [Displace modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Displace).

[image]