# How can I change an objects scale, and rotation using an Empty?

Tags: workflow

So I [previously asked a question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/how-can-i-separate-faces-without-the-edges) on how to separate the faces of an object like an Icosphere. *I decided that this next part would be best for a separate question.*

Taking that Icosphere and an Empty, how would a best be able to achieve the results shown in [these tutorials](http://www.cinema4dtutorial.net/?p=1293)? Here is what my object looks like:

[image]

So I need to be able to drag an Empty through the sphere and have the triangles scale, and or rotate inward or outward as seen in the image.

Comment: Can you please a description of what your trying to achieve? If the link goes down, no one will know what your asking. However, based upon the question in the title, I would recommend using parenting.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Oh yeah and I tryed parenting and it didn't work. Did you check the link?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Cast](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Cast) and [Wave](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Wave) modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

One way I found that gets a similar effect, is using hair particles to emit triangles:

1. Add a sphere as an emitter mesh:
   [image]
2. Add a plane and merge (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) two vertices to create a single tri:
   [image][image]
3. Set the Particle settings for the sphere to *hair*, select the tri as object in *Particle settings > Render*, disable *Emitter* so the emitter mesh is not rendered, and enable *Rotation* in *Render*.
   [image]
4. Now rotating the tri causes the particles to rotate as well:
   [image]
5. Force fields will also effect the hair particles, so you can get effects with them too.

## Duplifaces

This can also be achieved with duplifaces:

1. Parent the tri to an icosphere
2. Select the sphere, and enable *Duplifaces* in *Properties > Object panel > Duplication > Faces*
3. (Optional) Enable *Scale* and tweak scale settings.
4. You can apply the dupli objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (With the sphere selected)
5. Add a constraint to one of the now separate triangle objects (you might want to make these a *Group* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> so you can select them all easily with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> *> Group*)
6. You can then constrain each tri individually, select them all with the constrained tri active (yellow) and *object > constraints > copy constraints to selected objects*:

[image]

Note that with Duplifaces the trick of rotating the original tri still works, but force fields do not.

Comment: Can you expound on how to do the duplifaces I tried those steps and it didn't work so if you could put in more detail, on what exactly I need to do.

Comment: @OwenPatterson Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale an them apart and rotate them in if you use separate objects.

1. Separate the mesh by going into edit mode, selecting <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts*
2. Reset the origins for the objects by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and select *Origin to Geometry*.
3. Change the pivot point to individual origins:

   [image: Set the Pivot Point]
4. Press <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to rotate the objects.
5. To scale the objects away from each other, use the little button next to the pivot point menu:

   [image: scale away from each other]
6. Press <kbd>S</kbd> and scale away.